# how the hot-reload plugin is enable in vaadin 14

Tags: vaadin, livereload, vaadin14, hot-reload

I have a vaadin14 application and I activated the hot-reload capabilities (with spring-boot-devtools). So I have the vaadin widget on my webpage and when I do a change in the code, it builds and the widget is automatically refreshing my webpage to see changes.

Unfortunately I needed to compile another project (not vaadin) on java 8, so I change my env variables, make changes on the other project and when it was done, I changed again to return back to java 11. But now, I can build but I can't see the vaadin hot-reload plugin on my webpage, so I need to press F5 manually to see changes.

Do you know how the vaadin hotreload plugin is enable in the webpage ? How can I have it again ?

Thank you.

Comment: How are the two projects linked? How do you run them? Have you tried cleaning the projects and rebuild? It's seems very unlikely that two unrelated projects are breaking each other unless there is some hidden sauce to link them.

Comment: The 2 projects have no link together.
I tried to clean and rebuild several times, and I even rebooted my PC. Even I launc the project by console or with eclipse, the problem still continues.
And yesterday, whithout any raeson the vaadin live reload plugin re-appeared on the web page. I don't know why.
As i need to make changes on the other project today, I will check if th errors occurs again.
Thanks for helping